# How to add new value to current css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css style like this:

```
#div1 {
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
}
```

How can I add 20px to top value no matter what the current number is because the value should be dynamic. Thanks

Comment: [*what have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set new value in the callback function of [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value):

```
$('#div1').css('top', function(index ,value) {
    return value + 20;
});
```

For jQuery version 1.6+, you can use:

```
$('#div1').css('top','+=20px')
```

Comment: the `value` parameter is a string.. it won't work.. unless you parse value to int like: `return parseInt(value) + 20`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div1').css({top: "+20px"});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Returns current Top Value.
var origTop = $('#div1').position().top;

//Value you wish to increment original Top Value by.
var topIncrement = 20; 

// Sets new Top Value
$('#div1').css('top', origTop + topIncrement);
```

jQuery.position().top returns the int value for Top. 
you can then declare your variable you wish to increment by. 
Set the CSS value for the new Top Value in the third line of code. 
Should work. Please do correct if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) jQuery function to get or set css properties.

```
$('#div1').css('top', '+=20px')
```

Comment: Reason for down vote?

Comment: There's no reason to down vote this answer!
Just check [this example](http://api.jquery.com/css/#example-1-1) in jQuery Doc.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...

```
$('#div1').css('top','20px');
```